# Submit a form with ajax on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have this form that I would like to be submitted on page load.

My jQuery code is currently as follows:

```
<script> 
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
      document.getElementById('form1').submit();
    }); 
</script>
```

I have tried the ajax form plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) which does submit the form but I have no idea how to get it working with on page load:

```
  <script> 
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#form1').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank You"); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Help!

I just want form1 submitted once the page loads, the plugin looks like my best bet however I don't know how to get it working on page load

Comment: Would you be so kind and let us know whether you found another solution (and answer your question on your own in this case - so we can also benefit from your investigations) or one of the given answers fitted your needs (and mark the adäquate answer as accepted in this case to honor the communities efforts)? :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#btnSubmit').click(); //assuming this is your submit button
});
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: OMG Actually you helped a lot! LOLOLOL the plugin I'm using submits the form as soon as the button's clicked so this worked like a charm! Sorry for my stupid comment earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will do what you want :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  // #1 get the data to submit
  var jInput;
  var oData  = {};
  var aInput = jQuery('#form1 input');
  var i      = aInput.length;
  while ( --i !== -1 ) {
    jInput = jQuery( aInput[i] );
    oData[ jInput.attr('id') ] = jInput.val();
    console.log( jInput.val() );
  }

  // #2 submit data via ajax (method == 'post')
  // without response
  jQuery.post( 'url-to-send-ajax-request-to.php', oData );

  // with response
  jQuery.post( 'url-to-send-ajax-request-to.php', oData, function( sResponse ){
    alert( sResponse ); // would be the output of the file you sent your ajax request to
    alert('Thank You');
  });

});
```

PHP-file ('url-to-send-ajax-request-to.php'):

```
print_r( $_POST );
```

Comment: I understand this however what I'm wanting to do is a solution to have the form actually submit on page load via AJAX. So the codes above that I pasted do work however I just want a solution that will actually submit the form but on page load. I'm not extremely proficient in AJAX however I do understand the functions above.

Comment: See my edited answer if its still not what you are asking for please clearify your question...

Comment: Thanks! However the jQuery 'submit' function actually takes the user away from the page on submit i.e. doesn't do it through ajax.
The AJAX function I have  the ajaxform one works perfectly fine however it requires the user to click the submit button, I just want it to execute on page load. If anybody could help that'd be great

Comment: Your question is still not clear! You are asking about the jQuery.ajax ... itself or what?

Comment: Alright let me see if this makes sense:

I basically want form1 to be submitted without the user knowing it's being submitted.

So as soon as they land on a page that has form1 (it's fields are already pre-filled) it will be submitted but the user will not know that it has been.

Hence the ajaxform plugin looks like my best bet as it can submit the form without the page changing: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

However it works only when the submit button is clicked, I want the form submitted as soon as the page is loaded.

Comment: @Aaron do you necessarily must give the response as a form or is it just the need to submit data in general???

Comment: no need for a response, just submit the form discreetly :)

Comment: It's a pretty confidential project and the form code is reaaaally long  - trust me, the ID of the form is form1 and the form name is form1. The action can be taken as just process.php - thanks

Comment: Thanks @Axel for your help however it won't work since we don't have access to the url-to-send-ajax-request-to.php file so we can't edit it. Also the form has a ton of fields including radio and non <input> fields. This right here works perfectly fine: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ if there's anyway to make it occur on page load though that'd be great. However the solution above won't be the most ideal.

Comment: thanks! The guy above just gave me a solution that works perfectly fine - I was overly complicating the situation. Thanks for your help though.